# How to get pixeldata without using LockRect? (Performance issue)

Tags: c++, directx-9

I'm using these function someone post on StackOverflow, but the performance is toooooooo bad..

With out using this function( not capture pixel ) FPS show over 6k, but using this function, FPS show only 60!

So is there any fast method that can copy between video memory and system memory?

Anyone please?

```
HRESULT capture(IDirect3DDevice9* m_d3ddev, void* buffer, int& width, int& height, D3DFORMAT format)
{
    IDirect3DSurface9 *renderTarget = NULL;
    IDirect3DSurface9 *destTarget = NULL;
    HRESULT hr = m_d3ddev->GetRenderTarget(0, &renderTarget);
    hr = m_d3ddev->CreateOffscreenPlainSurface(width, height, format, D3DPOOL_SYSTEMMEM, &destTarget, NULL);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        printf("Failed  CreateOffscreenPlainSurface!");
    }
    hr = m_d3ddev->GetRenderTargetData(renderTarget, destTarget);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        printf("Failed  GetRenderTargetData!");
    }

    D3DLOCKED_RECT lr;
    ZeroMemory(&lr, sizeof(D3DLOCKED_RECT));
    hr = destTarget->LockRect(&lr, 0, D3DLOCK_READONLY);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        printf("Cannot lock rect!");
    }

    if (lr.pBits)
    {
        memcpy(buffer, lr.pBits, width * height * 4);
    }

    hr = destTarget->UnlockRect();
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        printf("Cannot unlock rect!");
    }
    renderTarget->Release();
    destTarget->Release();
    return hr;
}
```

Comment: Please link the question where you took that from. If it is exactly 60 FPS, my wild guess is that DirectX waits until VSync (backbuffer swap?) to be able to lock the surface.

Comment: @Acorn It shows 7 ~ 60 Frame. Not a VSync problems. like I said without that function fps shows over 6000.

Comment: Without that call your function does no work.  Why are you copying data off the GPU on a per frame basis?

Comment: @Yakk - Adam Nevraumont   cause I'm doing pixel work. pixel code is necessary.

Comment: GetRenderTargetData is the problem. it cause low fps i think. :(

Comment: If you are doing per-pixel work on a GPU buffer on the CPU, you are doing it wrong.  "I get low FPS" -- yes, that is what you get when you copy full frames from the GPU every frame.  You are asking for low FPS.  It might be possible to make it *less* painful, but it will always be painful.

Comment: @Yakk - Adam Nevraumont then what are the appropriate answers? Do I have to work on under CPU? using GDI?

Comment: I have no idea what you want to do with all of those pixels.  I'm just saying that it isn't practical to copy high FPS pixels from a graphics card to a CPU; and worse, if you want to copy it back.  If that is your plan, you have a bad plan and should rework it.  If you want, you could look up the memory bandwidth of your GPU to your RAM and calculate what the theoretical limit is (pay attention to bits vs bytes in the bandwidth numbers); possibly on some modern hardware with small displays it is now possible.

Comment: nahhhh.. why you avoid my question. Even if I have a bad plan, I have to do it. So  what could be "appropriate" answer to get high fps to get pixel code every frame?